# How to increase font size for command window in octave

Tags: octave

I was trying to figure out how to increase the command window text.
I figured out `legend`:

```
legend('{\fontsize{10} Low }', '{\fontsize{10} Medium }', '{\fontsize{10} High }')
```

I tried doing the same thing, but with `command`, `command_window`, and other variations. I have tried to right click on octrave shortcut for the octave gui and set the font there to much larger. I am running Windows 8.

Comment: File -> Preferences -> Terminal -> Font size ?

Comment: Oh I see.  I was doing the editor style, and it wasn't working.  It had a category for command so I just assumed that was it.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any GUI for octave? If so which GUI?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the top left nav bar: octave-gui -> preferences -> Terminal -> Font Size

NOT editor font size, which is fairly confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Change the font size in terminal doesn't work

It should be here. top nav bar: octave-gui > preferences > Editor Styles

select tab: Octave. and the first row Default-- change the font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to 
`Edit > Editor styles > change the font` (see the image)

[image]