# Changing font size in the command window of octave

Tags: octave

I recently started using the latest version of octave that is octave 4.2.1 on my windows 10. The font size on my command window appears to be very small and it's getting hard to see what I type. I tried finding how to change the font size on multiple sources including the manual and could not find it. Can anyone please the step by step procedure to change the font size in my command window? Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29454716/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase font size for command window in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454716/how-to-increase-font-size-for-command-window-in-octave)

Answer (score 0):

[Crossposting on the octave help mailinglist](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/no-subject-td4685139.html). OP "accepted" answer from Torsten:

> I guess you are using the gui. Here are the steps for changing the
>   font size:
>
> 1. Open the preferences via the menu "Edit/Preferences" or by typing "preferences" into the terminal
> 2. Go to the tab "Terminal"
> 3. Select the desired font size in the spinbox "Font size"